# How to find loop start and end in LLVM IR

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, clang

How to find starting and ending values of loop induction variable in LLVM IR?

```
for(int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    A[i] = 0;
}
```

Want to replace with a call to "zero(A,start,end)"

Or is it better done with clang AST? Are there facilities in clang to do this kind of changes?

Comment: Take a look at LLVM passes like `LoopSimplify`, `LoopUnroll` and the others which depend on `LoopInfo` analysis pass. The latter should provide enough information for your transform. Although, for the more complicated array index dependency analysis, you'd need something like `Polly` in addition to the existing LLVM features.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at the `SCEV` hierarchy of classes: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1SCEV.html